# postgres function is not executing properly

Tags: sql, postgresql

Here I have used like this but not working please provide me the solution

````
  IF  'select topic1 from tblscmipklimipcmapprovalio2269 t except select miptopic1 from tblmiptopic1master tm'    THEN
      BEGIN
          topic := topic1;
              execute 'insert into tblmiptopic1master (miptopic1 , createdby , createdon , updatedby , updatedon , active) values 
  (topic,22,'',55,'',1)';
          
      END;
  ```
````

Comment: Remove the single quotes around the select after the `IF`

Comment: If you want to insert only if a row does not exist, no need for PL/pgSQL. Use `insert on conflict do nothing` instead

Comment: And you don't need an IF or an execute.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for responding can you please give me an example for that

Comment: @wildplasser yes but I need to check the filed in that select query and if it there means, I need to insert that field in another table otherwise, I leave as it is

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do.  It is not obvious.

Comment: Actually, if we get the value from the select query means I need to insert that value in another table this is the logic actually @GordonLinoff

Comment: Also, your `IF  'select topic1 from ...` is not a scalar (sub)query. It can return more than one topic1 value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the topic to be unique, then you should let the *database* control the data integrity:

```
alter table tblmiptopic1master add constraint unq_tblmiptopic1master_miptopic1
    unique (miptopic1);
```

Then you would phrase the `insert` as:

```
insert into tblmiptopic1master (miptopic1, createdby, createdon, updatedby, updatedon, active)       
    select topic1, 22, '', 55, '', 1
    from tblscmipklimipcmapprovalio2269 t
    on conflict (miptopic1) do nothing;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot@gordon linoff

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into tblmiptopic1master
  (miptopic1, createdby, createdon, updatedby, updatedon, active)       
select topic1, 22, '', 55, '', 1
from tblscmipklimipcmapprovalio2269 t
where not exists ( 
   select * from tblmiptopic1master nx
   where nx.miptopic1 = t.topic1
   );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @wildplasser but please provide how to avoid repeated values are storing

Comment: You avoid storing repeated values by not storing them if the already exist. (indexes or unique constraints can help to enforce this)